# Problems In JavaScript Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, arrow-functions

I'm a newbie
I've download some source in this link
https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/react-redux-example
i have some proplem
in file src/app.js line 4

```
const applyFilter = searchTerm => article =>
  article.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
```

why this can't work with

```
const applyFilter = searchTerm => article =>{
  article.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
}
```

or

```
const applyFilter = searchTerm => {article =>
  article.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
}
```

and in line 14 when call the funtion

```
articles.filter(applyFilter(searchTerm))
```

```
const applyFilter = searchTerm => article =>
  article.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
```

this in my mind is call an arrow function inside an arrow function?
How can they put var 'article' in??

Comment: Please be more specific about what's your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow function syntax is kinda like this

```
(a) => b(a);

is equivalent to

function(a) {
    return b(a);
}
```

However, when you add `{}` to an arrow function, it changes the meaning:

```
(a) => { b(a); }

is equivalent to

function(a) {
    b(a); 
    // notice that this doesn't actually return anything, 
    // it just calls a function and does nothing with the result
}
```

So you have to add a return statement when you add brackets

```
(a) => { return b(a); }
```

Comment: Please don't answer this kind of question. (Downvote wasn't necessary)